# Problem with saving image

Tags: python, canvas, background, postscript

I have a problem with saving an image. I have following part of code:

```
self.canvas.postscript(file = filename, colormode = "color")
```

It works good, but when I set background color in canvas constructor (f.e. bg='red'),
finally image doesn't have this background color. It is still white.

Could anybody help me ?

Comment: for future reference, including more detail in your question will yield much better answers, and many more answers. Describe the libraries you're working with in this case, and include them as tags if they are relevant to what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're using Tkinter: is that right?

I believe the problem is that the bg argument is a general property shared by all widgets. It's really a part of how the widget is drawn on the screen and not a part of the image you're constructing in your canvas. I think the easiest thing for you to do is to draw a red box in your canvas for your background - that will then be included as part of the image saved in your postscript file.